# What will cause my application try to link a library does not exist?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I installed the opencv by apt before, and then I want to use some new features of opencv. So I use apt remove to uninstall it and build opencv by myself.
Howerver, my application tried to link the two version opencv at the same time.
I use ldd tool to check the link symbol.

```
ldd ./build/src/PersonBoatDetector | grep opencv
        libopencv_highgui.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.5 (0x00007f5784a33000)
        libopencv_ml.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.4.5 (0x00007f57847a1000)
        libopencv_videoio.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5 (0x00007f578451b000)
        libopencv_video.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.5 (0x00007f5784297000)
        libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5 (0x00007f5783f41000)
        libopencv_features2d.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.5 (0x00007f5783c67000)
        libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5 (0x00007f5781ef1000)
        libopencv_core.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5 (0x00007f5780aa8000)
        libopencv_highgui.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_videoio.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_imgproc.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_core.so.3.2 => not found
        libopencv_dnn.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.5 (0x00007f576e17f000)
        libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5 (0x00007f576dd66000)
        libopencv_flann.so.4.5 => /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.4.5 (0x00007f576cf24000)
```

Here is my cmake file. I tried to target the version of opencv but the result is same.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE yolov4DetectorSrc "*.h" "*.cpp")
add_executable(PersonBoatDetector ${yolov4DetectorSrc})
target_include_directories(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE ../ThriftModule)
find_package( OpenCV 4.5.1 REQUIRED )
target_include_directories(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS} rpc_client pthread m)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS REQUIRED filesystem program_options log log_setup)
target_link_libraries(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE Boost::filesystem Boost::program_options Boost::log Boost::log_setup)
find_package(CGAL CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE CGAL::CGAL)
target_link_libraries(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE swscale avformat avcodec swresample avresample avutil z rt stdc++fs hiredis paho-mqtt3as paho-mqtt3cs paho-mqttpp3 tbb gmp)
target_include_directories(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE ../thirdparty/darknet/include)
target_link_directories(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE ../thirdparty/darknet)
target_link_libraries(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE darknet)
add_compile_definitions(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE OPENCV BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
target_compile_features(PersonBoatDetector PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

I tried to use make --verbose=1 to show every makefile command. At the linking stage:
There is no opencv3.2 at this step. It is strange.

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable PersonBoatDetector
cd /home/robin/RLDNN/Yolov4PersonBoatDetector/build/src && /snap/cmake/793/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/BoatCamera.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/BoatCounterSuppotCam.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/BoatsNumInGateArea.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/CameraBase.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/CameraExtraBehavior.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/DarknetWrapper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/LLS.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/LabelImgXMLGen.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/LocalDemo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/MqttClient.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/PersonCamera.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/PicSimilarity.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/TimeStamp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/TrackableObject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/TrackableObjectsMoniter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/VideoObjDectConfig.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/base64.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/jpegBase64.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/log.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/redisutils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/PersonBoatDetector.dir/workthread.cpp.o -o PersonBoatDetector   -L/home/robin/RLDNN/Yolov4PersonBoatDetector/src/../thirdparty/darknet  -Wl,-rpath,/home/robin/RLDNN/Yolov4PersonBoatDetector/src/../thirdparty/darknet:/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gapi.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_alphamat.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_aruco.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ccalib.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudabgsegm.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafeatures2d.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaobjdetect.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudastereo.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn_superres.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dpm.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_face.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_freetype.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hfs.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_img_hash.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_intensity_transform.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_mcc.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_quality.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_rapid.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_reg.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_rgbd.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_saliency.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stereo.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_structured_light.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_surface_matching.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_tracking.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_xphoto.so.4.5.1 ../ThriftModule/librpc_client.a -lpthread -lm /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so.1.72.0 -lswscale -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lavresample -lavutil -lz -lrt -lstdc++fs -lhiredis -lpaho-mqtt3as -lpaho-mqtt3cs -lpaho-mqttpp3 -ltbb -lgmp -ldarknet /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_datasets.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_plot.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_text.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudacodec.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaoptflow.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudalegacy.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_optflow.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaimgproc.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudafilters.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.5.1 /usr/local/lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.5.1 -lthrift /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so.1.72.0 /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.72.0 -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so
```

Comment: `pkg-config --libs OpenCV`.

Comment: It seems that opencv4 has deprecated pkg-config.

Comment: Probably, old OpenCV is used by CGAL or other library, which is used in your project. You may try to examine with `ldd` all libraries passed to the linker. Not sure how could we help you.